# Angular 6 Form fields data to be cleared the first time the form page loads

Tags: angular, angular6, crud, angular-services

Working on angular reactive forms where I have a main form named xyzFrom for which the following happens:

1. The page loads and the user is supposed to enter values of the respective fields.
2. Then after filling is the submit.
3. Then I go to my main menu page find a search page where I get a set of values in the datatable, and along with it I have a favicon so on click of that favicon it will open to the main form ie the  xyzFrom with loaded values according to that filled on that specific id.

Issue here is since I have called the service on the `ngOnInit` the values are even loaded the first time even any service is actually called.
How do I solve this so it opens to a clear new form every time the new form is opened?

This is the component.ts file

```
 ngOnInit(): void {


    this.choosePolicyType = this.policyTypes1[0];


    this.vehicleDetailsForm = this.fb.group({
        first_name: [, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],

    })

this.getPolicyInfo();
} getPolicyInfo() {
this.policyService.getPolicyInfo().subscribe(
    (policyB: PolicyData) => this.displayPolicyB(policyB),

    (error: any) => this.errorMessage = <any>error

);}
```

And this is my service

```
getPolicyData(): Observable<PolicyData[]> {
return this.http.get<PolicyData[]>(this.serviceUrl);
```

}

Comment: Add any code that you tried.

Comment: @SudarshanaDayananda done added

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call on ngOnInit

```
xyzFrom.reset(xyzFrom.value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to reset the forms is -

this.formName.reset();

for more info on forms read out here

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html

form.reset() method works only for formControls reset call